# how to fix strip failure "because it is named in a relocation"

Tags: linux, strip

I am building a static library and I am trying to strip all of the non-public routines but I get this error:

```
strip: not stripping symbol `g722_state_update' because it is named in a relocation
```

How can I resolve this?

When I build and strip the shared version of my library I do not get this error.