# Incremental linking and relocation

Tags: c, linker, incremental-linking

My project have a several object files with project internal functions, and one object file which exposes functions for a public interface. My goal is to use incremental linking to combine all object files to a single file, and have this single file only expose the symbols needed for the public interface.

foo.c, public interface.

```
void bar(void);

void foo(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

bar.c, project internal function.

```
void bar(void)
{
}
```

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
$ gcc -c bar.c
$ ld -r -o combined.o foo.o bar.o
$ strip -N bar combined.o  
strip: not stripping symbol `bar' because it is named in a relocation
```

Both functions are already part of the same segment in the same object file, so I believe it should be possible to resolve the relocation during the link step? Is it possible to alter the `ld` command in order for the relocation not to be needed?

Comment: *bar* is not static so can be needed to link combined.o  with other objects ?

Comment: the old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294624/how-to-fix-strip-failure-because-it-is-named-in-a-relocation had no answer

Comment: bar() is not static because I need to access it from the foo file. But after linking combined.o, I do not want bar() to be visible anymore. Ideally ld should do the relocation so the symbol is not needed anymore, but I cannot convince ld to do that.
I have tried e.g. `-fvisibility=hidden` when compiling bar.c, but not been able to find a solution.

Comment: Why the votes down? This is a good question properly posed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree, so I UV

Comment: Apple’s ld has options for this. For example, you can use `ld -r -exported_symbol _foo -o combined.o foo.o bar.o` to request that `_foo` be exported, in which case unlisted symbols will be marked local instead of global, after which `strip -x` will remove them. There are related options to use a file to pass a list of symbols to be exported or to specify symbols not to be exported instead of specifying those to be exported. I do not know if these are on the mainline (non-Apple) `ld`.